# Use of "yori" in this sentence

Tags: particle-より

From what I can tell; this is a yes / no question coming from the line before it and the presence of "short form + の + かい".

> でもたまに思い出し、お前に問いかける
>
> 憎しみより深い幸福はあるのかい

Does it mean, "But sometimes I remember and I ask you if happiness (幸福{こうふく}) more profound (深{ふか}い) then hatred (憎{にく}しみ)?"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"Is there a happiness more deep than hatred?"

Perhaps breaking it down would help:

深い幸福 - deep happiness

深い幸福はある - There is a deep happiness

深い幸福はあるのかい - Is there a deep happiness?

憎しみより深い幸福はあるのかい - Is there a deep happiness that is deeper than hatred? OR Is there a deep happiness that is more so (より) than hatred --> "Is there a happiness more deep than hatred?"